# LINUX LDAP Domain with roaming profiles

Tags: linux, ldap, roaming-profile

I would like to set up a linux LDAP domain using Ubuutu as my client side. Currently i have an LDAP server setup and users can authenticate through the LDAP Server. But how to create to roaming profiles is becoming a challenge to me. I also have PC that has the storage to which i would like to map users home directories. Kindly help..

Answer (score 2):

If your clients are using Linux/Unix as well, you could export your storage via NFS, mount it on the clients and set the the home directory path accordingly in your LDAP directory.

What you would need:

- On the storage server, export the
  relevant directory via NFS (you have
  an NFS server package to be installed). You
  need to edit /etc/exports accordingly
  (see `man exports`).
- On the clients,
  mount your NFS to an appropriate
  location from `/etc/fstab`, possible
  to `/home` or `/mnt/home`.
- In the
  LDAP entries for your users, make
  sure they have an path for their home
  directory that matches your NFS mount
  point, i.e. `/home/joe`.

When users log into their workstation next time, they will use the home directory mounted via NFS.

[This entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) in the Ubuntu doc wiki gives detailed instructions to perform the steps I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Have created an interesting solution hope it helps -
Required items are -
- LDAP PDC
- NFS share to central storage where roaming profile are stored
- A home directory schema creating script, for creating home directory on central home directory

Procedure -
**Entry in /etc/rc.local**
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /*{central Storage Path}*/.home/ /home/
This copies the folders only from central profile to local profile. This helps when a person is logging in a different machine for the first time. As home directory folder gets created automatically and stays updated for all users created.

**Entry in ~/.bashrc** -- This is helpful if you are doing Command-line or SSH login.
rsync -av /*{central Storage Path}*/.home/$USER/ /home/$USER/ --size-only

**Entry in ~/.bash_logout** -- This is helpful if you are doing Command-line or SSH login.
rsync -av /home/$USER/ /*{central Storage Path}*/.home/$USER/ --size-only
This will copy home directory back from /home to central home directory.

**Entry in /etc/gdm/PreSession/Default** -- This is helpful if you are doing GUI login.
rsync -av /*{central Storage Path}*/.home/$USER/ /home/$USER/ --size-only

**Entry in /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default** -- This is helpful if you are doing GUI login.
rsync -av /home/$USER/ /*{central Storage Path}*/.home/$USER/ --size-only
This will copy home directory back from /home to central home directory.
***Optionally*** - we can also do following to clear out home directory from workstations but this will take time with every login.
rm -fvR /home/$USER/*

Testing currently in real working scenario... will post results and more refined workflow later.

Regards

Upen